# how to use Bayesian theorem and probabilistic analysis?

Tags: probability, bayesian

```
   could someone help me to solve this problem please ?
```

Your prize Rapid Ripe tomato plant has flowered and is ready to start producing fruit. If all goes well, your plant will produce tomatoes by the end of the week. It will then produce a new set of flowers and blossoms next week. Unfortunately, your area is subject to blossom wilt, which causes the tomato flowers to fall off. If the blossoms fall off, a new set of blossoms will not emerge until next week, and tomatoes will not be ready until the end of that week. Luckily, each time blossoms fall off, the plant builds up its resistance; the probability of each succeeding blossom falling off is then only half as much. You estimate that the probability of this first set of blossoms falling off is 0.40.

1. What is the probability tomatoes will be ready in
   the third week?
2. What is the expected number of weeks you will have tomatoes over the next three weeks?
3. What is the probability you will lose the blossoms one or more weeks of the next five weeks?

Comment: This looks like an exercise you're supposed to do. please add what you've come up with so far and if you're stuck ask a question so that we can help you.